# Updating Rails 4 code to Rails 4.2 code

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-4.2

I'm working through the Apress "Beginning Rails 4, 3rd edition" book. The book introduces you to Rails by building a blog application step by step. I'm about halfway through, and have received the following error message:

```
ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError in CommentsController#create
```

I've traced this to my comments_controller.rb file, which looks like this:

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :load_article

  def create
    @comment = @article.comments.new(params[:comment])
    if @comment.save
      redirect_to @article, :notice => 'Thanks for your comment'
    else
      redirect_to @article, :alert => 'Unable to add comment'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @comment = @article.comments.find(params[:id])
    @comment.destroy
    redirect_to @article, :notice => 'Comment deleted'
  end

  private
    def load_article
      @article = Article.find(params[:article_id])
    end
end
```

Specifically, the problem seems to be caused by line 5:

```
@comment = @article.comments.new(params[:comment])
```

From what I've gathered, the problem seems to be that the book I'm working through was written for an earlier version of Rails. I'm using Rails 4.2.0, and it seems that I ned to use different syntax. What do I need to change to get my code to work?

Answer (score 2):

You need a method that's private in your controller called `comment_params` (convention, you could call it anything)

Controller:

```
def create
  @comment = @article.comments.new(comment_params)
  if @comment.save
    redirect_to @article, :notice => 'Thanks for your comment'
  else
    redirect_to @article, :alert => 'Unable to add comment'
  end
end

private

def comment_params
  params.require(:comment).permit!
end
```

It's called strong_parameters and is a gem so you can google it to find it on github

`params.require(:comment).permit!` will permit anything though, you will probably want to limit it by passing attributes `params.require(:comment).permit(:name, :message)` - assuming you have name and message attributes.

You'll want to replace `params[:comment]` with the call to the `comment_params` method in your update method if you have one.

Answer (score 1):

you need to do this before you create your model object. Rails has to sanitize the parameters before you are allowed to put it in there.

```
comment_params = params.require(:comments).permit(:attribute1, :attribute2)
@comment = @article.comments.new(comment_params)
```

Answer (score 1):

Under the method `load_article` add the following method:

```
def comment_params
  params.require(:comment).permit( ... )
end
```

and replace the three dots with the attributes you need to allow.

Then in your create function you can write

```
@comment = @article.comments.new(comment_params)
```

You will probably need to do something similar in your `update` function.